# Inline Encapsulation stopped working

Tags: c#, class, encapsulation, getter-setter

I have been writing a app that consumes a web service, download JSON formatted data, deserializing it into classes. The service is PHP based (I believe).

Recently the web service has had an update that has had unexpected consequences on my class declarations.
Up until recently I have been using this line for one of the Class Variables

```
public string consent_id { get { return consent_id.ToUpper(); } set { consent_id = value; } }
```

and it has seemingly been working nicely. However since the update to their service. This has been causing a stack overflow exception and I have had to change the code to

```
 string Consent_id;
 public string consent_id { get { return Consent_id.ToUpper(); } set { Consent_id = value; } }
```

It feels like the first line has started recursively calling the set encapsulator.

Does anyone know why the first one stopped working? The actual reason its throwing a stack overflow exception? Is there a way to set the Getter without setting the Setter inline so I don't to encapsulate everything that's requires a modified Getter?

Thanks

Comment: In your first line you recursively call getter when you invoke `return consent_id.ToUpper();`. So, it's a good practice to use backing filed in this case. And you cannot set a body of getter without setting a body of setter

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria In testing we took the ToUpper() out and it did not change. It was the Setter throwing the exception too.

Comment: Did you test the first example or the second with the backing field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option would never have worked.

It's throwing a stack overflow exception because in the getter you're calling the getter, which calls the getter, which calls the getter, and so on, until you run out of stack space.

Comment: Is there another way to do it inline? I cant seem to be able to set one without the other.  I thought the setter wouldn't call itself from inside itself. Something new every day.

Comment: @Seige If you don't want to use an auto-property, then you'll need to store the value *somewhere*, whether that's in a field, another property, some other location, or something.  The only way to have an implicit field is for an auto-property.

Comment: With an auto-property, is it not the same as the full default encapsulation but in shorthand? or does it do something different internally? I would have thought putting the default code in the setter would be the same as the auto-property. Hence my code.

Comment: @Seige An auto property is shorthand for a field that is set in the setter and that gets that field in the getter.  Your code has *no* field, and calls the property setter in the property setter, and calls the property getter in the property getter.